# How to reset java script search filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have a search box to filter the result set.Any ways to reset the filtered result to original result ?

```html
<input type="text" id="MValues" ng-model="MSearch.name">
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="section in sections | filter: Msearch as MSearchresults " >
   <label>{{ section.name }}</label> 
</div>
```

Comment: Just make a button to set `Msearch` to it's original value? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Once it set , the result set no showing.The filter doesn't apply the original result set